# Scope of css .form-group-sm

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Why `.form-group-sm` reduces a `.form-control` but not a `.control-label` except when inside a `.form-horizontal`? This forces a custom css or the use of `<small>` tag with the `<label>` tag. Is it by design or a missing?

From bootstrap.css:

```
.form-group-sm .form-control { ... }
.form-horizontal .form-group-sm .control-form { ... }
```

Sample code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Small label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="formGroupInputSmall" placeholder="Small input">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Probably by design. If it was not inside .form-horizontal, .control-label would be treated as a block element. If it is in .form-horizontal, then you would be displaying form elements inline, and would have to set a size for .control-label.